# Converting ListPreference string to integer gives "Integer cannot be cast to String" exception

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

In my settings, have a list preference. I created an arrays.xml (see code below) and set the values to my ListPreference (see code below).

**Arrays.xml**

```
    <string-array name="listArray">
        <item>minutes</item>
        <item>hours</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="listValues">
        <item>60</item>
        <item>3600</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

**ListPreference**

```
<ListPreference
            android:title="Set time: minute hour"
            android:key="listPref"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/listArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
```

I know that I have to use string arrays and that every value retrieved from preferences will be a String. As you can see below, I convert the String to an Integer.

But when I do so, I get: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
 int listPrefs = Integer.valueOf(sharedPref.getString("listPref", "3600"));
```

Comment: What happens if you just try calling `getInt()`? It feels like `SharedPreferences` is seeing a pure-numeric `String` and converting it to an `Integer` for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassCastException` appears to be thrown from `sharedPref.getString()` so therefore I would assume that `PreferenceManager` indeed does have `listPref` backed by an Integer.

Simply use `getInt()` and your error should go away.